# SSO Application error:MMC could not create the snap in

Tags: single-sign-on, biztalk

I tried to open the SSO Application Configuration in the BizTalk server and I couldn't see any data stored previously but there is an error screen stating

MMC could not create the snap in error. The snap-in might not have been installed correctly
CLSID:FX:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

Can you please help me what went wrong and what needs to be fixed.
I was able to use it properly before

Comment: What version of BizTalk?  Is there anything in the Event logs?

Comment: BizTalk version is 2013R2.Yes there is an error logged as:
Cannot open database "SSODB" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'XXXXXX'.
Seems like my access to SSODB has been revoked. Granting the access would resolve the issue or there is something else that is required to get the SSO application working?

Comment: Your user should be part of the SSO Administrators group.